# Opening program via keyboard binding from systray C#

Tags: c#, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-events, dock, password-generator

Working on a end of the year project for school and chose to create a password generator that stores them  locally and encrypted. I have everything working for the most part and just adding some little touches in the end. Pretty much right now I have it where you minimize it stores in the windows 7 systray/notification dock and then you can right click and have a menu and such. I was wondering on how I could have it where you hit a certain key combination anywhere on windows and have the program become visible and un minimize. I have looked around the web and couldn't really find a solution. Any help is appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should search for "global keyboard hook" in google, there is lots od examples.
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook.aspx

Comment: Looks a little bit dated, and doesn't really help or explain much. Also where is "Gma.UserActivityMonitor.dll" so that I can get "GlobalEventProvider". The article explains hooks for 2008 but not 2010. I am sure there is a newer way.

Comment: No, use a hot key, RegisterHotKey() API function.